# Подвисания при скроллинге в Chrome в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, radeon

Установил Ubuntu 16.04.3. Открыл Firefox, скачал google-chrome-stable. В Firefox никаких лагов не наблюдалось, все вполне плавно. Поставил Chrome и при скроллигне появляются на доли секунды горизонтальные линни прошлых изображений, т.е. скорлим экран и картинка в некоторых местах опускается сразу, а в некоторых спустя пару мгновений.

Думаю, что дело в драйверах на видеокарту, возникает вопрос как установить, как проверить какие стоят, какие не стоят. У меня Radeon, почитал, что из коробки в Ubuntu идет открытая версия драйвера, но можно скачать версию pro с закрытыми исходниками и она быстрее. Пробовал скачивать, ставить, в итоге черный экран, снес ОС, поставил заного.

В общем цель: заставить ОС работать плавно, если это решается через драйвер, то как установить его и как узнать какой устанавливать, если проблема не в драйвере, то какие могут быть решения?

Comment: Единственный хоть как-то рабочий вариант - это через "рекомендуемые драйверы".